# Alternative for org-mode elementary OS-style

Tags: applications

When I still was using openSUSE, I used org-mode in emacs as my note-taking program. There is an annoying bug  in Ubuntu that makes it impossible to open Emacs without being root and I also didn't have the time to learn how to configure and theme Emacs to my liking in elementary OS so it would fit better in the overall OS, so I switched to Zim.

But  I really loved using org-mode to take notes especially with all the short cuts for navigation and reordering the document. It's something I really miss. Does anyone know a way to either properly configure and theme Emacs so it will blend in elementary OS or a way to use org-mode without Emacs or maybe an elementary styled program that has (most of) the same functionality as org-mode?